# Configuración correcta de Amazon Linux AMI con dominio principal puerto 80 y 443

Tags: linux, ec2

la consulta es rápida y concisa.

Tengo un dominio que apunta a Route53 de amazon y dicho servicio está configurado a una instancia  Amazon Linux AMI. La instancia tiene instalado apache y mysql. Ya tiene agregado un dominio principal el cual le instalé el certificado lets encrypt el único gran problema es que:

No puedo hacer que www.midominio.com y midominio.com redireccione a https://midominio.com pues en las primeras dos opciones se muestra la pantalla por default de apache y https:// si funciona correctamente.

Supuestamente tengo configurada la instancia para que lea la configuración desde su propio archivo de dominio. A continuación muestro que tiene cada archivo para ponerlos en contexto y me logren ayudar a identificar mi error por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias desde ya.

Answer (score 0):

una disculpa y gracias por todo, ya logré solucionarlo. En el archivo de configuración de mi dominio solo agregué estas lineas.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName wwww.midominio.com
    Redirect permanent / https://midominio.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName midominio.com
    Redirect permanent / https://midominio.com
</VirtualHost>
```